# Insert or Update if duplicate based on unique index

Tags: php, sql, primary-key

Here is what I want to do. Insert if the unique index (code) doesn't exist in the table already. If it exists then simply update the row.

I can't use primary key because it is Auto Increment ID. Here is the code

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO codes (code,registration,country) 
VALUES ('$war','$regi','$country') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE code='$war', registration='$regi', country='$country'";
```

But it doesn't work because I think it is checking for duplicate primary key. So when I try to insert the row in which the value of column code is same as previous row I get Duplicate entry 'xxx' for key 'code' error. So how to make this work for unique index code ?

Ahmar

Comment: Can you share you table information.  It is important to understand this when working with duplicate key syntax.

Comment: Table Only Contains 4 columns id(pk,A.I) all other three columns code,registration and country are varchar. Code is set to unique

Comment: Try removing the `code = '$var'` part from the `update` statement.

Comment: Perhaps you have another column or set of columns that are unique?  Can you edit your question and show the table definition?

Answer (score 0):

`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` works with `UNIQUE` indexes as well as `PRIMARY KEY` values. Try setting one of the values you are trying to update to be `UNIQUE` on your database table.

Comment: I am trying to update the row. And code column is already unique that;s why I get duplicate key for column code error?

Comment: Have you tried using the `code=value('$war')` syntax?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is set `code` to be a unique index.  Then, anytime you try to do an insert where `code` matches it will update instead.

Alter this code as needed

```
alter table `table` add unique index(`code`);
```

Comment: I already added the code index as unique column that's why I get duplicate key for column code error?

Comment: Then something is not set up properly.  Can you share your table structure with us?  Also, can you share your index info as well?  Are you sure `code` is set up as a `unique index` and not just an `index`?

Comment: Here is what I am using to add unique index $sql="ALTER TABLE codes
ADD UNIQUE INDEX code(code);";

Comment: Table Only Contains 4 columns id(pk,A.I) all other three columns code,registration and country are varchar. Here is table structure

Comment: @GordonLinoff is right in his comment.  Remove the `code = '$var'` in the `On Duplicate Key` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, having a primary key on your table will not allow you to insert duplicate key values.

In the past, I have used something like this:

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM codes
WHERE code = '$war'

Then if the count is > 0, you know there's a duplicate and you do:

UPDATE codes
SET registration = '$regi', country = '$country'
WHERE code = '$war'

Otherwise you do:

INSERT INTO codes (code, registration, country)
VALUES ('$war', '$regi', '$country')

However, if we assume you're using MySQL, you might be able to make use of either INSERT IGNORE or REPLACE.

If you use:

INSERT IGNORE codes (code, registration, country)
VALUES ('$war', '$regi', '$country')

The values will be inserted if the code does not already exist. If the code does exist, no record is inserted and MySQL will silently discard the statement without generating an error.

I think what you probably want is this:

REPLACE INTO codes (code, registration, country)
VALUES ('$war', '$regi', '$country')

REPLACE INTO behaves just like INSERT INTO if the record is new. But if the primary key is duplicated, it will perform an UPDATE instead.

Again, INSERT IGNORE and REPLACE INTO are for MySQL only.

Reference: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-handling-duplicates.htm